# umount busy target

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, mount

I've recently installed Ubuntu on a Lenovo/Windows10, and during installation I chose the option "*delete your existing operating system and replace it with Ubuntu*" which I thought it had worked fine. But when I restart my laptop pressing F12 I can still see the Windows OS and Debian (which I used for a little while) on the device specs. I thought both windows and debian would not be on the machine by now. 
Now I'm trying to create a new partition table, and so I deleted all partitions except for the current one (/dev/sda2) because I just can't.

- I tried using GParted.
- I tried running ~$ umount -l /dev/sda2
- I tried from root ~# umount --force /dev/sda2

Nothing works. What should I do?
Btw, I'm only using 15GB out of 500GB..which sucks. Should I use something like *Darik's Boot and Nuke* to wipe everything and install ubuntu again from my flash drive?

Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend to do a fresh install from flash drive and maybe use lvm in case you want to resize partitions later.

Comment: yeah... i guess I'm gonna do that. thanks, dude!